# Show/Hide a component in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

We are trying to build our first site on Sitecore SXA.

Is there a way to show/hide a rendering based on a field value or context?

for example

1. hide a link or a button if the user IsAuthenticated
2. hide a component if a boolean field value is 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SXA renderings are just like any other Sitecore components.

You can just use standard Sitecore personalization for them with conditions

1. [Except] where the current user is annonymous
2. Where the [specific] field [is equal] to 1

[image]

[image]

[image]